# Moving Whole Wordpress File to a New Host

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have back up everything and move whole file into new host, but when I try to access my wp-admin dashboard, it's come with error:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/home/next/domains/nextsalon.co.id/public_html/wp-content/themes/nextsalon/assets/css/color_options.css) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/next/domains/nextsalon.co.id/public_html/wp-content/themes/nextsalon/lib/theme-scripts.php on line 219

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/next/domains/nextsalon.co.id/public_html/wp-content/themes/nextsalon/lib/theme-scripts.php:219) in /home/next/domains/nextsalon.co.id/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few links you should refer before moving your wordpress file

1)**[Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)**

2)**[Moving A WordPress Website Without Hassle](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2013/04/08/moving-wordpress-website/)**

3)**[Hostgator Wordpress Move](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/website-transfers/how-to-transfer-your-wordpress-blog-from-one-host-to-another-host)**

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the useful links that Vaibs_Cool posted, I cannot stress this enough: take extremely good care with the database before moving it around. **Back it up first**. You most probably need to use this tool as well, if you're using a theme with serialized data: http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ (use with care as well)